# How to install older version of sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am facing some "UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES" problem for my custom dependencies with latest version of sbt(0.13.8)

I want to install older version of sbt, Do we have any command by which I can install older version of sbt ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define the sbt version by writing the one you need in `/project/build.properties`

It would be something like:

```
sbt.version=x.xx.x
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the following command for a Debian-based Linux:

```
sudo apt-get install sbt=0.13.13
```

Comment: with this set prior 
echo "deb https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/debian all main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
echo "deb https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/debian /" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt_old.list
curl -sL "https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823" | sudo apt-key add
sudo apt-get update